# PDF file not opening

Tags: java, jsf, pdf, jsf-2

I have Java code to open the pdf file in Java and it is running perfectly.

Code is

```
    try {
        File pdfFile = new File("/Users/alkandari/Desktop/SMART/Fahim/test.pdf");
        if (pdfFile.exists()) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File is not exists!");
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However when I put this in some method say `showMyPDFFile()` and try to call that on `commandLink`, pdf doesn't get open. It says `Awt Desktop is not supported!`.

```
 <h:commandLink value="View PDF/ DOC"
 action="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.showMyPDFFile()}" />
```

Any idea why pdf is not getting opened?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf primefaecs will make your development faster

Comment: Dude, this Java code runs in webserver, not in webbrowser.

Comment: You should download the file using `<h:link>` and make sure this call is not handled via AJAX.

Comment: @BalusC : I got what you want to say... Bit Lazy to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just to check, you're writing a web application, right?

The `Desktop` class refers to the local desktop - so it's for *local GUI client applications*. Even if it were supported, you'd be opening the PDF on the *server's* desktop - not the *client's* desktop, which I assume is what you're after.

It sounds like you should basically just be linking straight to the PDF file (as  URL). You'll need to make the PDF available via your web server, of course.